# Bad connection emulation for video stream

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-streaming, vlc

what is the easiest way to check friezes and lags for different internet speeds of a video file? Maybe some players can run local videos with problem emulation?

Answer (score 1):

Streaming behaviour under bad network will highly depend on what kind of protocol you using.

For example, with HTTP-based protocols like HLS / DASH you will experience freezes if bandwidth is not enough. With UDP-based protocols like WebRTC there's gonna be artefacts / freezes / drop in bitrate.

The way you can test it is:

1. Run media server in docker or on linux server
2. Install network emulation tool like [netem](https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem). It allows you to limit bandwidth, introduce package loss, jittering and tweak many other parameters
3. Play video; adjust netem setting (it can be done in runtime)